# Does this equation have an analytical solution?

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, computational-mathematics, fluid-dynamics, simulation

I am doing a simulation on OpenFOAM where I am looking at a porous media flow though a region. I have no problem with that but what I am wondering is, if there is not obstacle in the region does the governing equation have an actual solution or would I still need to use some numerical method to solve it ? If so what simplifications can I make sense there is no obstacles in the region (if there is any) ? The governing equation is an extension of the Navier-Stokes equations that adds a sink term:

$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\gamma\rho u_i) + u_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (\rho u_i) = - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x_i} + \mu \frac{\partial \tau_{ij}}{\partial x_j} + S_i
$$

Where the $S_i$ term is defined as: 
$$ S_i = - (\mu D + \frac{1}{2} \rho |u_{jj}| F)u_i $$

These equations are found in the following [paper](http://www.tfd.chalmers.se/~hani/kurser/OS_CFD_2008/HaukurElvarHafsteinsson/haukurReport.pdf) and I am using the same solver, and sort of configuration for what I am looking at as well.

The variables in the above equation are given as: 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&\gamma \in [0,1] \text{ is the porosity of the object} \\
&\rho \text{ is the density} \\
& u \text{ is the flow velocity} \\
& \tau \text{ is the Cauchy-Stress Tensor} \\
& P \text{ is the Pressure} \\
& S_i \text{ is the sink term} \\
& D,F \text{ are Darcy-Forchheimer constants} \\
& \mu \text{ is inversely related to the Reynolds Number}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: You would have to provide some more definitions here, like what is $\gamma,\rho,u $ ... And just my intuition, if this is basically Navier-Stokes but "more complicated", an analytical solution is highly improbable.

Comment: My apologies I will add that in now, essentially it is the characteristics of the liquid.

Comment: For the geometries you have, no. Maybe if you have an squared section duct and a linear equation (assume small perturbations of variables w.r.t. the base flow) you could (improbable more than possible) reach an analytical solution.

Comment: Well the reason why I am wondering is because I am looking at having the equation without an obstacle in the domain.... essentially I want to compare how the fluid flows with and without the obstacles in the domain, where I will use Open-FOAM to solve the system with an obstacle in the domain. Because of this I figured the geometry would be simplified. Also to the domain i'm interested in is strictly a rectangle domain.